# Can I publish a template app(paid) on the App Store

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

Please let me know Can we upload the template app on the App Store?
Because we are making a app, this is like a module based app so the buyer of that app can use the app code to use in their apps.

So please let me know could we upload this to the App Store?
If no, where can I publish this app to generate revenue?

Comment: consider Custom B2B instead

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because app store submission policy is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165/65839) and better addressed by [Apple support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/65839).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an app store's policies and procedures, rather than programming. See [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand correctly your question, but if you want to publish a paid app that would **require** other app(s) to work, then it would be rejected.

Please see this section of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/PerformanceTips/PerformanceTips.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH7-SW1) (emphasis mine) :

> (vi) Apps should allow a user to get what they’ve paid for without
>   performing additional tasks, such as posting on social media,
>   uploading contacts, checking in to the app a certain number of times,
>   etc. Apps should not force users to rate the app, review the app,
>   **download other apps**, or take other similar actions in order to access
>   functionality, content, or use of the app.

Otherwise, please give us more informations about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think he want to sell app templates thru an app.

Comment: I want to sell the this app as the template like the templates made in the PHP.
Because the code of the app we want to sell. We have provided the app with the module so the buyer of this app (Source code) can use the source code too.